# Create a pandas.PeriodIndex from a list of quarter strings in format YYYYQ

Tags: python, pandas

I know a bit about `pandas.Period` and `pandas.PeriodIndex`. But I am not able to make them fit to my use case.

I have a list of *quarter strings* in format `YYYYQ`:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'quarter': ['20214', '20222']})
```

How can I create a `PeriodIndex` or `Period` (each element) of it?

I am not able to do this

```
pandas.PeriodIndex(df.quarter, freq='Q')
```

because my strings doesn't contain a `q` or `Q` at the right position. I could do some string manipulation in a first step to insert a `q` at the right position. But I wonder if `PeriodIndex` gives me the ability to specify a format string like `YYYYQ`.

Answer (score 1):

You can rework the string to the 'YYYYQX' with [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for automatic detection by [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then convert to period:

```
(pd.to_datetime(df['quarter'].str.replace(r'(?=\d$)', 'Q', regex=True))
   .dt.to_period('Q')
)
```

output:

```
0    2021Q4
1    2022Q2
Name: quarter, dtype: period[Q-DEC]
```

or for a PeriodIndex:

```
pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['quarter'].str.replace(r'(?=\d$)',
                                                        'Q', regex=True)),
               freq='Q')
```

output:

```
PeriodIndex(['2021Q4', '2022Q2'], dtype='period[Q-DEC]', name='quarter')
```

##### regex:

Here using a lookahead to insert a Q before the last digit:

```
(?=\d$)    # match last digit
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eMJDiA/1)

Answer (score 1):

Add `q` before last digit by [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and then is possible converting to quarters by your solution:

```
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['quarter'].str.replace(r'(\d{1})$', r'q\1', regex=True), 
                               freq='Q')
print (df)
  quarter
0  2021Q4
1  2022Q2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df['quarter'].str.replace(r'(\d{1})$', r'q\1', regex=True))
0    2021q4
1    2022q2
Name: quarter, dtype: object
```